# onKeyUp function not calling second time

Tags: android, onkeyup

I have been trying to built an app based on [GHOST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_(game)) game.
I have written an onKeyUp function which only accepts lowercase alphabets and adds it to a string called wordfragment and then calling the function computerTurn in it. But i had seen after successfully running first time i.e. calling the computerTurn function and getting return statement from computerturn function it(onkeyup) does not works second time.
Here my code to onKeyUp function.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int KeyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    char ch = (char)event.getUnicodeChar();
    if( !( ch >= 'a' && ch <='z'  ) ) {
        return super.onKeyUp(KeyCode, event);
    }
    wordFragment = wordFragment + ch;
    label.setText(COMPUTER_TURN);
    text.setText(wordFragment);

    userTurn = false;
    computerTurn();
    return true;
}
```

and my code to computerTurn function is

```
private boolean computerTurn() {
    if(wordFragment.length() >= 4 && dictionary.isWord(wordFragment)){
        label.setText("Computer wins");
       // challenge.setEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        String word = dictionary.getAnyWordStartingWith(wordFragment.toLowerCase());
        if(word!=null){
            Toast.makeText(GhostActivity.this, "comp word found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            wordFragment += word.charAt(wordFragment.length());
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(GhostActivity.this, "comp word not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            label.setText("User Wins!!");
            //challenge.setEnabled(false);
           // wordFragment += (char)(random.nextInt(26) + 61);
        }
    }
    // Do computer turn stuff then make it the user's turn again
    userTurn = true;
    label.setText(USER_TURN);
    text.setText(wordFragment);
    Toast.makeText(GhostActivity.this, "return true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android softkeyboards rarely use key events.  The correct way to use an android soft keyboard is via InputConnection.  Only hardware keys generally issue key events.  Basically you're coding this the right way for Windows or web, but the wrong way for Android.